# How to make a coloured stroke line around a Form Section in SwiftUI

Tags: forms, swiftui, sections, stroke

Using Swift-5.4, iOS14.5, XCode12.5,

I am trying to create a coloured stroke line around a Form Section in SwiftUI.

My first trial was with `.background` like shown here:

(but this does not work since it encircles every line of the Section-items instead of the entire Form-Section)

```
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {

        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2)
        )
    }
```

My second trial was with `.overlay` like shown here:

(But again, same mistake - this does not work)

```
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {

        }
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
            .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2)
        )
    }
```

What can I do to get a yellow line around a Form Section ?

[image]

For completeness reasons, here is my entire Form :

```
struct MyView: View {        
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 1.1")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 1.1")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 1.2")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 1.2")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 1.3")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 1.3")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
            }
            .background(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2)
            )

            Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 2.1")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 2.1")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 2.2")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 2.2")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
                HStack {
                    Text("Title 2.3")
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Text 2.3")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                }
            }
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.1")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.1")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.2")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.2")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.3")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.3")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                }.padding(8).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2))
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 2.1")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 2.1")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 2.2")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 2.2")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 2.3")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 2.3")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                }.padding(8).overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - it helped somewhat. However,  there are three major issues with your solution: a) the yellow line is not at the outermost rim of the Form Section. And b) the form-section-height gets much smaller than before. And c) the lines between the items is gone.... I feel that with your approach that I have to rebuild the entire Form-Stack and this shouldn't be the case, should it ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.1")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.1")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.2")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.2")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text("Title 1.3")
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Text 1.3")
                            .lineLimit(1)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                    }
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 2)
                .background(Color.yellow))
        }
    }
}
```